# How do i match ip address to zip code for neighborhood sessions?

Tags: sql

We're looking to gauge volume of events by consumer location, but we only have ip address for users in the logged out state- what can we do with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you need to provide quite a bit more detail. Do you have the data in a database table? If so, please provide details of the layout of data in the table. What have you tried so far, what results did you get? If you got errors, what were they? SO generally works best when you've tried something and have encountered problems and the community ALWAYS appreciates detail. Good luck!

Comment: this SO might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348614/how-to-determine-a-zip-code-and-city-from-an-ip-address